# Setup website with SSL in apache server hosting multiple websites

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I have two websites with domain aaa.com and bbb.com located in the same apache server. bbb.com has a SSL Certificate while aaa.com does not. I have created the following bbb-ssl.conf for bbb.com which contains the SSL location

Here is the file I have under /etc/apache2/sites-available
- default-ssl.conf
- aaa.conf
- bbb.conf 
- 000-default.conf
- bbb-ssl.conf

Now I found that when i access https://www.bbb.com/a.php, it actually links to https://www.aaa.com/a.php

I would like to know seek your help the cause of this problem. Thanks!

Here is my conf content

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName aaa.com
        ServerAlias www.aaa.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName aaa.com
                ServerAlias www.aaa.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
                # error, crit, alert, emerg.
                # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
                # modules, e.g.
                #LogLevel info ssl:warn

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
                # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
                # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
                # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
                # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
                #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

                #   SSL Engine Switch:
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
                SSLEngine on

                #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
                #   the ssl-cert package. See
                #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
                #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
                #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

                #   Server Certificate Chain:
                #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
                #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
                #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
                #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
                #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
                #   certificate for convinience.
                #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

                #   Certificate Authority (CA):
                #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
                #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
                #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
                #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

                #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
                #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
                #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
                #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
                #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

                #   Client Authentication (Type):
                #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
                #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
                #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
                #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
                #SSLVerifyClient require
                #SSLVerifyDepth  10

                #   SSL Engine Options:
                #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
                #   o FakeBasicAuth:
                #        Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
                #        the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
                #        user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
                #        Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
                #        file needs this password: `----------'.
                #   o ExportCertData:
                #        This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
                #        SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
                #        server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
                #        authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
                #        into CGI scripts.
                #   o StdEnvVars:
                #        This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
                #        Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
                #        because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
                #        useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
                #        exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
                #   o OptRenegotiate:
                #        This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
                #        directives are used in per-directory context.
                #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
                #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
                #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
                #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
                #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
                #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
                #        This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
                #        SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
                #        the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
                #        this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
                #        mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
                #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
                #        This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
                #        SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
                #        alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
                #        practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
                #        this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
                #        works correctly.
                #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
                #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
                #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
                #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
                #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
                #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
                # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                #               nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                #               downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

bbb.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName bbb
        ServerAlias www.bbb.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bbb/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        <Directory "/var/www/bbb/public_html">
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Content"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

bbb-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName bbb
                ServerAlias www.bbb.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/bbb/public_html

                # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
                # error, crit, alert, emerg.
                # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
                # modules, e.g.
                #LogLevel info ssl:warn

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
                # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
                # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
                # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
                # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
                #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

                #   SSL Engine Switch:
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
                SSLEngine on

                #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
                #   the ssl-cert package. See
                #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
                #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
                #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/bbb.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/bbb.key

                #   Server Certificate Chain:
                #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
                #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
                #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
                #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
                #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
                #   certificate for convinience.
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/bbb.ca-bundle

                #   Certificate Authority (CA):
                #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
                #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
                #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
                #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

                #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
                #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
                #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
                #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
                #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

                #   Client Authentication (Type):
                #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
                #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
                #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
                #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
                #SSLVerifyClient require
                #SSLVerifyDepth  10

                #   SSL Engine Options:
                #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
                #   o FakeBasicAuth:
                #        Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
                #        the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
                #        user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
                #        Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
                #        file needs this password: `---------'.
                #   o ExportCertData:
                #        This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
                #        SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
                #        server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
                #        authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
                #        into CGI scripts.
                #   o StdEnvVars:
                #        This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
                #        Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
                #        because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
                #        useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
                #        exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
                #   o OptRenegotiate:
                #        This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
                #        directives are used in per-directory context.
                #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
                #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
                #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
                #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
                #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
                #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
                #        This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
                #        SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
                #        the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
                #        this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
                #        mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
                #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
                #        This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
                #        SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
                #        alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
                #        practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
                #        this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
                #        works correctly.
                #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
                #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
                #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
                #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
                #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
                #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
                # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                #               nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                #               downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And if you change the SSL ``VirtualHost`` for ``bbb.com`` to not use ``__default__:443`` and instead use just ``*:443``?

Comment: i have changed it to <VirtualHost *> but the problem is still there

Comment: I said ``*:433`` not ``*``.

Comment: Tried but he page is still redirecting to another site

Comment: What do you have under ``sites-enabled`` directory?

Comment: Same files as in sites-available

Comment: I would like to ask how the apache knows it needs to refer to bbb-ssl.conf?

Comment: It matches the request ``Host`` header against value of ``ServerName`` or ``ServerAlias`` directive. The port matches port what is in the ``VirtualHost`` directive.

Comment: Based on that what you have shown, it isn't consistent. Ensure ``ServerName`` is same for both 80 and 443 versions.

Comment: I guess the problem is that it's referring to the default-ssl instead of bbb-ssl.conf

Comment: You don't have ``www.bbb.com`` as ``ServerAlias`` in SSL version.

Comment: And change ``ServerName bbb`` in non SSL to ``ServerName bbb.com``.

Comment: Ok, let me check about it. Thanks

Comment: i have updated the bbb-ssl. but the server is still referring to the default-ssl.....

Comment: Your example in question still show ``<VirtualHost _default_:443>`` for the ```bbb`` host rather than ``<VirtualHost *:443>``. If that just because you haven't updated the question, even though you updated other parts? Anyway, next step is to introduce a syntax error into ``bbd-ssl.conf`` and restart Apache just to make sure it does error, ie., file is being processed. Add a line with ``XXX`` by itself. That is enough to trigger an error.

Comment: Seems ok now, can I know what's the _default_ there mean? Thanks !

Comment: Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default It is used to mark the virtual host that handles all requests that couldn't be matched by hostname. Prior to ``_default_``, Apache would use whatever ``VirtualHost`` was the first encountered for same port.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your help.